# Making my comments on OTHERS' walls visible on MY wall

Tags: facebook

How do I make my posts, comments etc., on other people's walls, visible on MY wall?

Comment: Are they visible only to you?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to see on your wall? I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

YOU can't.

You would need to have the other people change their privacy setting to allow Posts from Others (in this case, YOU) to bee seen by: Public/Friends/Friends of Friends/etc.

Each individual person controls who can see what from their wall.